# I found some weird exploit

Tags: hacking

I call it 'Meta-jacking'.

So this website I found has a meta with `content=""` and whatever you type in the description displays your text in the content. So I took advantage of this and typed:

`0;//wwww.google.com"http-equiv="refresh"`

and sure enough it redirected to google, is this some sort of XSS?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific... "has a meta" - what kind of meta? "type in the description" - do mean in a form/input control? It might be a vulnerability - depends what you can do with it. What you have described isn't necessarily XSS either.

Comment: Ok it's not my website, but in the website is does this weird thing where it puts whatever you write in your description in to a format like this: <meta name="description" content="Test" />
let's say I put my description to 'Test', then it would look like that. I took advantage of this by typing: 0;//www.google.com"http-equiv="refresh" so now the page would redirect to google because it looked like: <meta name ="description" content='0;//www.google.com'http-equiv="refresh">

Comment: "write in your description" - is this some kind of profile page? Or a page generation tool of some kind? Or literally just a free-form type the description and hey-presto?

Comment: It's a profile type of thing

Comment: That would seem to be a XSS-type vulnerability, since presumably anyone can potentially view your _malicious_ "profile" page and be unwittingly redirected. At the very least it could simply _break_ the profile page - which innocent users might do by accident!? (NReilingh pretty much nails it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much a textbook example of XSS. When a site takes input and then serves it back to you in an executable manner, the site is vulnerable because a ne'er-do-well can direct a victim to the legitimate website in such a way that malicious code is "injected" into the session. The user thinks they are safe because the site is legitimate, HTTPS encrypted, etc. -- but since they were sent there by a malicious source leveraging the XSS vulnerability, the session is compromised.

This is exactly why we tell people not to click links in email.